# python - auction script (input from file to dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary

So i have a file, for example:

```
Book
Peter 500
George Peterson 300
Notebook
Lizzie 900
Jack 700
```

The integers are their bids for the prizes. I want to read the names and the bids to dictionary, but i got stuck here:

```
d = {}
with open('adat.txt') as f:
    d = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f)
for keys,values in d.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)
```

So, how to read the data in correctly?

Comment: How do you want to deal with the lines that have "Book" or "Notebook"?

Comment: I guess you can either ignore them, or better, have them as a key of a dictionary and then have the value be a dictionary of name/bid-price values.

Comment: i have to keep them :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip over "invalid" lines like `Book` and `Notebook`:

```
d = {}
with open('adat.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        try:
            price = int(words[-1])
            name = ' '.join(words[:-1])
            d[name] = price
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            # line doesn't end in price (int() raised ValueError)
            # or is empty (words[-1] raised IndexError)
            pass

for key, value in d.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have to keep the prizes. I have to write the prizes to a txt file with the name and the highest bid of the guy who won the prize

my output have to look like this:
Book -- Peter -- 500
Notebook -- Lizzie -- 900